# Python nosetests skip certain Tests

Tags: python, pylons, nosetests

I am working on tests for a web application written in python.

Suppose I have 5 tests in my test_login.py module.

Every single test is a Class.

There is often one, base test that extends TestFlow class, which is our predefined test class.

And then other tests in this module extend that base test.

For instance :

```
#The base test 

TestLogin(TestFlow):
    #do login_test_stuff_here

#Another test in the same module

TestAccountDetails(TestLogin)
    #do account_details_test_stuff_here

...
```

It's actually quite handy, because in order to test for example AccountDetails user has to be logged in, so I can just inherit from TestLogin test and I am ready to test other functionality as a logged user.

All tests are in Project/project/tests folder.

We use nosetests with option --with-pylons to run tests.

And my question is if there is a way to mark certain TestClass as "Do not test this one".

Because I don't want to waste time to execute these "base tests" directly, because they will be execute by other tests that iherit from them.

There will be probably tones of these tests and I want to save every single second where it is possible.

I've already found something like Skip, SkipTest or @nottest, but these only work for **test_methods** within a ceratin TestClass, so I don't think it will work here, were I have a single class for each test case.

Answer (score 12):

Form nosetests it can be done as below by specifying the attributes
http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html

> Oftentimes when testing you will want to select tests based on criteria rather than simply by filename. For example, you might want to run all tests except for the slow ones. You can do this with the Attribute selector plugin by setting attributes on your test methods. Here is an example:
>
> ```
> def test_big_download():
>     import urllib
>     # commence slowness...
>
> test_big_download.slow = 1
> ```
>
> Once you’ve assigned an attribute slow = 1 you can exclude that test and all other tests having the slow attribute by running
>
> ```
> $ nosetests -a '!slow'
> ```

Answer (score 5):

You CAN actually use the skiptest for Classes too.

```
import unittest

@unittest.skip("Class disabled")
class TestLogin(TestFlow):
    ...
```

Comment: Note that on Python <= 2.6 you need to install unittest2 for this to work.

Comment: That wont work for the provided use case. Adding the skip decorator to the base class will cause all sub classes to also be skipped. Even if you used `@unittest.skipIf(True, "base class")` on the base class, and `@unittest.skipIf(False, "")` on the subclasses, the subclasses still get skipped

Answer (score 2):

http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html

> Writing tests
>
> As with py.test, nose tests need not be subclasses of
>   unittest.TestCase. Any function or class that matches the configured
>   testMatch regular expression ((?:^|[\b_\.-])[Tt]est) by default –
>   that is, has test or Test at a word boundary or following a - or _)
>   and lives in a module that also matches that expression will be run as
>   a test. For the sake of compatibility with legacy unittest test cases,
>   nose will also load tests from unittest.TestCase subclasses just like
>   unittest does. Like py.test, nose runs functional tests in the order
>   in which they appear in the module file. TestCase-derived tests and
>   other test classes are run in alphabetical order.

note the regex and rule above.  name your functions/methods/classes to not match the regex , and they won't be run.

that being said, I don't recommend your suggestion of chaining inheritance for tests.  it's a recipe for frustration and mess.

you would likely be better off with making a mixin class , or defining a base class that doesn't have any actual tests - but has a lot of helper functions which inheriting classes can call and use as their own.

if you look at the tests of the more popular packages, they almost all use that approach.

Comment: Note that the match regex is not the only gate for inclusion - *nose will also load tests from unittest.TestCase subclasses*.  It appears to do this for anything that it imports as well.  I have a test named `FooMixin` in a module named `foo_helpers.py` that is being treated as a test simply because it is derived from `unittest.TestCase`.